# What is the best way with Apache to redirect a blank subdomain to another subdomain?

Tags: apache, url, redirect, dns, subdomain

I want any request to http://example.com/* to be redirected to http://www.example.com/*.

Where * is any arbitrary path.

Comment: Use "example.com" instead of foo: someone will actually own and use the foo domain.  Are you sure is isn't serving malware or porn?  Anyway, normal practice to redirect in the other direction:  www.example.com should point to example.com, not vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Apache's [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html) module to do a permanent redirect like:

```
RedirectPermanent / "http://www.example.com/"
```

Place the redirect inside the blank subdomain's virtualhost block or root level `.htaccess` file.

The trailing / on "http://www.example.com/" is crucial.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add another option here that I've used to allow for other specific hosts as well.  For example if you wanted a dev.example.com and a blog.example.com site in addition to your www.example.com site, put this in your root level .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```